# Vector bundles vs algebraic cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

For integral schemes, the Picard group is isomorphic to the group of Cartier divisors modulo linear equivalence.

What is the correct analog of this isomorphism, for higher codimension Chow groups vs appropriate groups of vector bundles modulo an appropriate equivalence relation? What about higher Chow groups (after Bloch - Beilinson)?

Comment: For a smooth, separated scheme over a field, part of the "Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch package" is that the Chern character defines an isomorphism between the associated $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the associated graded pieces of the gamma filtration on the K-group and the associated $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the Chow groups.  In cohomological degree $1$, this is the usual isomorphism of the $\mathbb{Q}$-Picard group and $\text{CH}^1\otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes. But the Pic-CH1 isomorphism does not require denominators. Is this because, when $p$ (codimension) is 1, then $(p-1)! = 1$, and to get rid of unnecessary denominators in higher codimension, one should only invert $(p-1)!$?

Comment: @BBSch Actually, if $dim(X)=n$ for your (smooth) variety $X$. I'm pretty sure that to get GRR you only need to invert primes dividing $n!$. And I think the reason for the integral result for codimension 1 is more subtle than what you elude to, its a sort of avatar of the fact that line bundles and cohomology are not far from each other (think $BU(1)=K(Z,2)$)

Comment: For a more algebro-geometric interpretation: think about how weil divisors and line bundles determine each-other in the smooth case. It has nothing to do (a priori) with GRR. The fact that GRR requires inversion indicates (to me) that its really a different sort of statement (much more subtle).